# Is it possible to deploy akka-http to JBoss?

Tags: scala, jboss, sbt, akka, akka-http

We are developing an akka-http application. Our infrastructure team requires us to deploy it to JBoss. Is it possible, if yes, how?

I found a plugin called [xsbt-web-plugin](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin), it converts a sbt application to a *war* file. That's all I have so far.

Comment: Akka API is both Scala and Java friendly, and in the end is compiled as bytecode for JVM, so I don't see why I could not be possible.

Comment: It sounds like your infrastructure team doesn't seem to understand what _akka-http_ is

Comment: Did you even ask your infra team one simple question: "But why"?